# The brighness slider isn't visible in the system menu and I don't know how to display it

Tags: gnome, brightness

Ubuntu version : jammy 22.04.4 LTS.

It's been months since I tried to fix the problem I had, the brightness slider wasn't working; it didn't change the brightness even when I lower the value.

However, I tried to fix it and made mistake now the slider isn't visible, I'm using another application to lower the brightness, but I prefer if I could make the menu the way it was when I installed Ubuntu.

Here is the picture, normally there should be a slider to change the brightness but the mistake I made that slider disappear:

[image]

Comment: please [edit] your question with further information. Which Ubuntu product/version are you using and when you say "brightness slider" how does that relate to the picture you posted which indicates a headphone symbol  I see no brightness slider there. Also add in what you did to "fix it" as we have no idea what action you have so far taken which would have "unfixed" anything

Comment: @graham the brightness slider is missing that's the problem

Comment: @graham sadly it's been months, i forget what i did trying to fix the problem.

Comment: please [edit] your question. What distro/version of Ubuntu are you using and how did you navigate to that menu option pictured?

Comment: Are you using a desktop with an external monitor, @ihab ??

Comment: No, i'm using a laptop with no external monitor.